# SonarQube quality gate is not showing after version upgrade to 4.3

Tags: sonarqube

We upgraded our SonarQube to 4.3 recently, and since that, some of our projects will not show any Quality gate status. Some projects are marked as green or red, while some projects are just not displaying any icon in the dashboard or in project details view. They should pass the gate though, since all criterias are met.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [migration process from a previous version to 4.3](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.3+Upgrade+Notes) creates one Quality Gate per profile that defines Alerts, but does not try to associate projects to these newly created quality gates. You have to manually re-associate projects to quality gates, eventually getting rid of duplicate quality gates. Once this is done, you should get the expected results in the Quality Gate widget.

Please also note that you can select an optional default Quality Gate, which will be used for projects that don't explicitly use one.

Comment: Thanks @Mithfindel, that was the case. In previous upgrades I cant remember that we ever had to re-apply these quality gates, so I didn`t think of it. Some projects no longer gets any coverage though, but I guess thats another issue. I think it relates to Jacoco. Thanks.